# Cannot find 'HttpRequest' even when ext installed

Tags: http, request, php

So, I've searched and searched. And I finally was able to get the image below:

Showing that php_http is installed! I've added

```
extension = php_http.dll
```

to my php.ini file and downloaded php_http.dll and it is in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\ext

And as my WAMP shows, php_http is enabled. Why do I still get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\wamp\www\q\xxxx.php on line 17
```

[image]

My code is:
(I get the error at the line "$r = new HttpRequest('http:/......"

```
// phpinfo();

class Xxx {

function __construct() {
}


function generate(){
    $r = new HttpRequest('http://www.whatever.com', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
    try {
        echo $r->send()->getBody();
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        echo $ex;
    }
}

}

$x= new Xxx();
$x->generate();

?>
```

Comment: What does your PHP.ini say, as far as that extension being loaded?

Comment: This is my php.ini [link](http://pastebin.com/5Yv1FmfK)

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed.  I meant `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I actually can't find the HTTP there.. But here it is: [link](http://pastebin.com/LZJ23Cg9)

Comment: I am having the same issue. dll is in the right place and I added the extension to my php.ini but still get the same error. I triple checked that I was editing the correct php.ini file by using phpinfo.

Comment: I think it can be a problem with with mixing of x86 and x64